# How can I avoid "no response from server URL" exception when using hub on Selenium remotewebdriver when object is not found?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the code I am getting error on line 1. Instead of returning true or false it throws an exception " No response from server for url: `http://test:4444/wd/hub/session/1382359342795/element`

Getting error on line1 :

```
Boolean tInputElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator")).Enabled;
if (tInputElement.ToString() == "True")
{
   IWebElement InputElement=driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator"));
   InputElement.SendKeys(InputData);
}
```

Please suggest how can I avoid no response error and catch objectnotfoundexception. Please note I am running this code using Hub.

This is how I got this working :

int _TotalTimeToWait = 0;

```
            int TotalTimeToWaitinSecs = 40;

            while (_TotalTimeToWait < TotalTimeToWaitinSecs && driver.FindElements(by).Count == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                _TotalTimeToWait++;

            }
            if (_TotalTimeToWait == 0) { driver.FindElement(by).Click(); Thread.Sleep(2000); }
            else { throw new ElementNotVisibleException(); }

            _TotalTimeToWait = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no property like Enabled for WebElement, but it does have a IsEnabled() method, so try:

```
if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator")).isEnabled())
{
   IWebElement InputElement=driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator"));
   InputElement.SendKeys(InputData);
}
```

Or something like:

```
IWebElement InputElement=driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator"));

if (InputElement != null && InputElement.isEnabled())
{
   InputElement.SendKeys(InputData);
}
```